# Java asynchronous execution increases CPU 100%

Tags: java, spring

Introduction:

I've developed a class which would accept number of `Tasks`, execute them in parallel and await for results particular amount of time. If some of the tasks failed to finish by given timeout it will interrupt entire execution and return only available results.

Issue:

All works fine at the beginning but after some time CPU usage increases until 100% and application obviously fails to response.

Could you please try to help me find an issue or suggest better solution how I could achieve the same goal?

Code:

**TaskService.java**

```
public abstract class TaskService {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger InfoLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("InfoLogger");
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger ErrorLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ErrorLogger");

    @Autowired
    private TimeLimiter timeLimiter;


    public List<TaskResult> execute(TaskType taskType, TimeUnit timeUnit, long timeout, final Task... tasks){

        final List<TaskResult> taskResultsStorage = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            timeLimiter.callWithTimeout(new Callable<List<TaskResult>>() {
                @Override
                public List<TaskResult> call() throws Exception {
                    return run(taskResultsStorage, tasks);
                }
            }, timeout, timeUnit, true);

        } catch (UncheckedTimeoutException e) {
            String errorMsg = String.format("Time out of [%s] [%s] has been exceeded for task type:[%s]", timeout, timeUnit.name(), taskType.name());
            ErrorLogger.error(errorMsg, e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String errorMsg = String.format("Unexpected error for task type:[%s]", taskType.name());
            ErrorLogger.error(errorMsg, e);
        }

        return taskResultsStorage;
    }



    protected abstract List<TaskResult> run(List<TaskResult> taskResults,Task... tasks) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException;

}
```

**AsynchronousTaskService.java**

```
public class AsynchronousTaskService extends TaskService {


    private CompletionService<TaskResult> completionService;

    public AsynchronousTaskService(ThreadExecutorFactory threadExecutorFactory){
        this.completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<TaskResult>(threadExecutorFactory.getExecutor());
    }


    @Override
    protected List<TaskResult> run(List<TaskResult> resultStorage, Task... tasks) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        List<Future<TaskResult>> futureResults = executeTask(tasks);
        awaitForResults(futureResults, resultStorage);
        return resultStorage;
    }


    private List<Future<TaskResult>> executeTask(Task... tasks){

        List<Future<TaskResult>> futureTaskResults = new ArrayList<>();
        if(tasks!=null) {
            for (Task task : tasks) {
                if (task != null) {
                    futureTaskResults.add(completionService.submit(task));
                }
            }
        }
        return futureTaskResults;
    }

    private void awaitForResults(List<Future<TaskResult>> futureResults, List<TaskResult> resultStorage) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        int submittedTasks = futureResults.size();
        int taskCompleted = 0;
        if(futureResults != null){
            while(taskCompleted < submittedTasks){
                Iterator<Future<TaskResult>> it = futureResults.iterator();
                while(it.hasNext()){
                    Future<TaskResult> processingTask = it.next();
                    if(processingTask.isDone()){
                        TaskResult taskResult = processingTask.get();
                        resultStorage.add(taskResult);
                        it.remove();
                        taskCompleted++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ThreadExecutorFactory.java**

```
@Component
public class ThreadExecutorFactory {


    private int THREAD_LIMIT = 100;
    private final Executor executor;

    public ThreadExecutorFactory() {
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_LIMIT,
                new ThreadFactory() {
                    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                        Thread t = new Thread(r);
                        t.setDaemon(true);
                        return t;
                    }
                });
    }

    public Executor getExecutor() {
        return executor;
    }
}
```

**Task.java**

```
public abstract class Task<T extends TaskResult> implements Callable<T> {
}
```

**TaskResult.java**

```
public abstract class TaskResult {
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the THREAD_LIMIT? E.g. to the number of cores of your system (e.g. using `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`)?

Comment: On that subject having more threads than processors  (or 2*processors for hyperthreaded cpus) will **dramatically** reduce performance. It may not be your issue but 100 threads is a bad idea

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys, I will try to reduce number of threads in the pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `awaitForResults` contains a busy loop:

```
while(taskCompleted < submittedTasks){
    ...
    while(it.hasNext()){
```

This will eat CPU like crazy, and hinders the actual threads. You should either add a sleep like for instance

```
 Thread.sleep(1000);
```

This is Quick&Dirty but will help solving the 100% cpu. Alternatively but more effort is to implement some signalling mechanism so the loop waits for a signal from one of the finished tasks.

Like others suggested, it likely doesn't make sense to have 100 threads if they're all cpu-bound, but I doubt that is really your problem.